# Where to report address location in the wrong spot for Google Static map

Tags: google-maps

I used the utility to determine that the location is different on the static google map than it is on the Google maps website:

http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/geocoder/singlegeocode.html

Here is the address that is incorrectly placed on the static map:

126 Airport Road Shamokin, PA

Where do I report this issue or get it resolved?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a data problem, report the issue on [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/).

1. [Search for the address](https://www.google.com/maps/place/126+Airport+Rd,+Monroe+Township,+PA+17870/@40.8166093,-76.8606523,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89cf3fa53d27a0f9:0x71e2467ce84008a4!8m2!3d40.8166093!4d-76.8584636)
2. Click "Send feedback in the lower right hand corner of that map, then "Report a data problem".

Comment: The address is listed correctly on Google Maps.  The issue is just on the static Google Map api.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (or raise an issue on the issue tracker if you're positive the request is correct).